# What can I use as synonymous for "related" in this context?

Tags: phrase-request, synonyms

What can I use as synonymous for the word **related** in this sentence?
Can I use **in the event of** as synonymous for **in case**?

> Next, the value of the mac variable is tested to know when the system has to delete the **related** (*relevant*) data from the database **in case** (*in the event* or *on condition*) the route and direction were detected by the WiFi AP

Comment: Personally I'd use 'determine' rather than 'know', and 'associated' or 'linked' for related, 'In the event' would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used in place of your original sentence:

> Next, the mac variable is tested **to determine** if the system **needs to** delete the **relevant** data from the database **when** the route and direction *(of what?)* ***was*** detected by the WiFi AP.

Since you are trying to *figure out* (***determine***) when something needs to be done.  Once it is figured out, the system then will perform an action (***needs to***). **When** describes the timing around the action.

Your sense of **relevent** is correct to use since the **relevent** data is what is focussed on, some of the data may be **related** but not **relevent** and would not need to be deleted.

**Testing** the mac variable implicitly figures out its value.

There may still be some ambiguity since the reader does not know **what** *route and direction* is being referred to. If it is **any** detection of *route and direction*, then **in the event** ***that*** can be used, but is more wordy than **when**.

> ...from the database **in the event that** the route and direction was detected...

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the word *affected*, if the data was somehow changed by the condition. As for *in case*, you can simply use the word *if*:

> Next, the value of the mac variable is tested to know when the system has to delete the **affected** data from the database **if** the route and direction were detected by the WiFi AP.